# Train and test split not seperate

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe of shape (2714,3) and I'm creating a data structure with 24 timestamps and 1 output, where: `train =  2761 * 0.8`.

After splitting the train and test using the below method:

```
X_train, y_train = X_train[:train], y_train[:train]
X_test, y_test = X_train[train:], y_train[train:]

X_train.shape, y_train.shape, X_test.shape, y_test.shape
```

I get this output:
(2171, 24, 3), (2171, 1), (0, 24, 3), (0, 1)

Why is `X_test` and `y_test` receiving `0` here?

Comment: On the first line, you overwrite `X_train` and `y_train` to only have `train` number of values. When you use them on the second line, you will have a problem. You could use a new variable name after splitting on the first name.

Comment: Check this out, much easier solution ;) 
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: just do this line first: `X_test, y_test = X_train[train:], y_train[train:]'